# Erro no Git me ajudem por favor

Tags: git

Todos os comandos que eu dou no git no meu linux aparece esse erro e eu não consigo terminar o trabalho por favor me ajudem como resolver

> ```
> root@joao-pc:/home/joao# git status
> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> root@joao-pc:/home/joao# git push
> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> root@joao-pc:/home/joao# git pull
> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você usa o comando `git clone <url>` uma pasta é criada com o mesmo nome do projeto presente no servidor. Você só consegue usar os comandos do `git` dentro desta pasta ou apontando para ela. Seu erro é pelo fato de estar usando os comandos fora da pasta. Há vários tutoriais na web ensinando passos de como trabalhar com o `git`, recomendo a você estudar um pouco sobre. Abaixo deixo um link de um tutorial simples:

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html

Comment: obrigado cara .. vou pesquisar aqui pra ver se resolvo esse problema